# Need help with getting a ViewModel to show on startup

Tags: wpf, mvvm

This question is in relation to: 
Beginning a WPF/MVVM application: Navigating between views
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72724/Beginning-a-WPF-MVVM-application-Navigating-betwee.aspx

I have asked the author of the article on his blog about how to approach this issue, however i am still stumped.

This is my App.xaml.cs

```
namespace PlatformXpress
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var container = new MicrokernelContainer();
        container.RegisterA<IMainViewModel>(typeof(MainViewModel));
        container.RegisterA<IHomeViewModel>(typeof(HomeViewModel));
        container.RegisterA<ICompanyOverviewViewModel>    
        (typeof(CompanyOverviewViewModel));
        container.GetA<IMainViewModel>().NavigateToView(HomeView);
        Container.InitializeContainerWith(container);
    }
}
}
```

Now everything works as it is supposed to with the example provided (i have changed things to suite my usage), and with my query the suggestion was to add the container.GetA line. In VS 2010 the only problem is at the end of said line @ (HomeView), thats the view i need to fire up on startup and i just cant seem to get it to work. the error is there is no applicable varable.

I have searched google for uses of the container.GetA and the return results are of no use.

Someone on here will probably be able to solve this one quite easily with just one look!

Cheers
Rohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of the `HomeView`:

```
container.GetA<IMainViewModel>().NavigateToView(new HomeView());
```